# java method has throws in it's prototype but does not throw any exception from it's body

Tags: java, exception

I am using different methods with exception handling in a chain system.

Please find the structure of my code below :

```
 mainflowMethod {

     try{
           outerMethod();
        }
        catch(SystemException se){

          //handle exception here
        }

        catch(BusinessException be){

          //handle exception here
        }

    }


   outerMethod throws SystemException, BusinessException {

    try{
         innerMethod();

        if(some_condition_matched){

        throw new SystemException(errcode1111);

        }
     }
     catch (OTHERException) {
       //some other exception handling
       // but neither SystemException nor BusinessException
     }  

   }


   innerMethod throws SystemException, BusinessException {

     doProcess();

    }


   doProcess throws SystemException, BusinessException  {

    throw new BusinessException(errcode2222);

   }
```

Now the doubt is :

1. whether the **BusinessException(errcode2222)** will reach to the mainFlowMethod() or it'll be lost anywhere ??
2. whether the **SystemException(errcode1111)** will reach to the mainFlowMethod() or it'll be lost anywhere ??

Please help me to get out of this doubt. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why don't you run it and find out for yourself? The code is right in front of you!

Comment: Suggestion to do things differently: try to push your methods into different classes; because that will allow you to **mock** such other classes. And all of a sudden you are able to write unit tests that guarantee you that an exception thrown somewhere is caught elsewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your example;

doProcess always throws BusinessException so never `if(some_condition_matched){` line runs.

Throwed BusinessException catched on mainFlowMethod.

if doProcess does not throw BusinessException and condition_matched, outermethod throws SystemException and catched by mainFlowMethod.

You want to have a look [Checked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) and [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement.
>   All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by
>   Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses.

So checked exceptions never lost and you have to catch them otherwise your code never compile.

But unchecked exceptions may cause your application crash.

Answer (score 1):

Both exceptions you will get in the mainFlowMethod() because you don't catch them in your methods: doProcess(), innerMethod() and outerMethod().

Comment: But without throwing it from inside will it be propagated back to the calling method ?

Comment: Without throwing it, if your exception extends Exception class (but not Runtime) you must catch it in the method where it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If either of those exceptions is actually thrown, then they will propagate to `mainFlowMethod()` and will be caught there.

If neither exception is not actually thrown, the question is moot.

Your code doesn't show where `BusinessException` is thrown, but it could potentially be thrown in `innerMethod()`, or it could be thrown in a future version of `innerMethod()` ... if it is implemented in a separate class.

In general, exceptions are not lost.  They are either caught or they propagate.